# Repeatedly checking entire scripting dictionary via loop bad practice? VB6

Tags: vba, loops, dictionary, optimization, vb6

I have a loop that checks for values and adds them to a dictionary if they do not exist. This check happens inside of a loop so it happens repeatedly. As the dictionary grows I imagine there is an inner loop going on with each check that is becoming costly. In an effort to speed up my entire routine I am wondering if this might be something I should optimize? If so, how?

```
  keycnt = 1
  For x = 1 to 500000
  STRVAL = returnarray(8, x)
            If Not STRDIC.Exists(STRVAL) Then
               STRDIC.Add STRVAL, keycnt
               keycnt = keycnt + 1
            End If
  next x
```

Comment: Where is STRVAL coming from?  Without knowing that it's difficult to tell what you're asking here?  In any case, the advantage of using a dictionary is that key lookups are very fast - typically lookup is via hashed keys and not just a simple loop.

Comment: It's just some value I set based on a recordset I am pulling using ADO. As I loop through the recordset I assign the value. I removed all of that to simplify my question because I don't really want anyone focusing on that.

Comment: your answer TIM is helping. That's what I am asking. Is it okay to hit the dictionary lookup repeatedly or is there a better method.

Comment: No it's *designed* to be hit!

Comment: thank you Tim !  I added a little more context. STRVAL comes from an array that was loaded by ADO using  recordset.Getrows

Comment: A better way is to add it, it will error if it already exists. Test for the error if you care. This way you only look up the dictionary once - when it is added. Your code searches twice - once to see if it exists and then when you add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dictionary is a `Scripting.Dictionary` and not some [poorly implemented] custom-made data structure class, then a key lookup should be ***O(1)*** complexity, not ***O(n)*** as you seem to imply; the growing number of keys has no impact on performance.

Key lookup in a hash table or dictionary is basically free, the only thing to fix in that code is the indentation.

Comment: yes its a Scripting.Dictionary. Thank you Mat's Mug. I wasn't sure how the lookup in the dictionary was happening and I was afraid that nesting it in a giant loop was a mistake.